# Filter events with JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have four selection for searching events in a database like "cinema", "theater" ecc. The code of selection is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header">
 <h1>App menus</h1>
 </div>

 <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
 <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
  <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" >
    <label for="day">Select day from</label>
    <input type="date" name="bday" id="bday">
  </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="day">Select day to</label>
    <input type="date" name="bday" id="bday">
  </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="event">Select Event</label>
        <select name="event" id="event">
            <option value="alle">All events</option>
            <option value="ev1">Event 1</option>
            <option value="ev2">Event 2</option>
            <option value="ev3">Event 3</option>
            <option value="ev4">Event 4</option>
            <option value="ev5">Event 5</option>
            <option value="ev6">Event 6</option>
            <option value="ev7">Event 7</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="luogo">Select Luogo</label>
        <select name="luogo" id="luogo">
            <option value="alll">All Luoghi</option>
            <option value="lg1">Luogo 1</option>
            <option value="lg2">Luogo 2</option>
            <option value="lg3">Luogo 3</option>
            <option value="lg4">Luogo 4</option>
            <option value="lg5">Luogo 5</option>
            <option value="lg6">Luogo 6</option>
            <option value="lg7">Luogo 7</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Atm I'm creating the event. But, the question is: how can I filtrate with js code the event in base of time/location/event tipe?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The question is unclear.

Comment: I'd like to create a filter like this website: http://verybello.it/?lang=it but I don't have idea about the filter method of events.